# Angular2 adal.js - #id_token in URL

Tags: angular, azure, angular2-routing, adal.js

I'm using adal.js in Angular2 project to authenticate Azure AD. After AAD authentication id_token is being appended to redirectUri, but Angular2 is not accepting #id_token in url parameter.

**Response URL:**
*https://localhost:44345/#id_token=some_jwt_token*

**Angular 2 Error message:**
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Is there any way to strip out id_token from url or handle this '#id_token' param in router module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your rooting file add something like :

```
{ path: 'your_url/:token, component: your_component}
```

and in case you want to make a link you may use this :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/your_url', { token: 'whatever' }]">image a dragon</a>
```

in case : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-router-links

Answer (score 0):

In MsAdalAngular6Module config, set navigateToLoginRequestUrl to true

`MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
      tenant: '...',
      clientId: '...',
      redirectUri: "...",
      endpoints: {
        "..."
      },
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, <------------ This one
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    }),`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about angular 2, but the almost similar issue I was facing in angular 8. On successful login, Azure AD redirect users desired redirect URL but with #id_token=some_jwt_token. To resolve this issue I have used the approach described in the link https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/issues/46

Which basically does the following

```
 constructor(private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const urlFragments = window.location.href.split('#id_token');
    if (urlFragments.length > 1) {
      this.location.go(this.location.path());
    }
  }
```

Do no forgot to import the location

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

I am using

```
"@angular/common": "8.2.14",
"microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0",
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use question mark, xxxxx/#?id_token=some_jwt_token.
That is what I did for my application SSO.

In your component:

```
token: string;

constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(paras => {
            this.token = paras['id_token'];
        });
      }
}
```